# How to change options in child dropdown depending of selected option in parent dropdown with javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I am working on a dynamic dropdown menu made of a parent and a child as the following:

parent :

```
<select id="category_select">
  <option value="1">Electronics</option>
  <option value="2">Appliances</option>
</select>
```

Child :

```
<select id="type_select">
  <option value="1">Phones</option>
  <option value="1">Tablets</option>
  <option value="2">Couch</option>
  <option value="2">Refrigerator</option>
  <option value="2">Vacuum</option>
</select>
```

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

if the selected option has a value of `1` in `category_select`, then options available in `type_select` should only have a value of `1` and all other options should disappear.

Here is the JS :

```
    "use strict";
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('category_select').addEventListener("change", function() {
        function parent_() {
            let parent_ = document.getElementById('category_select');
            let ParentVal_ = parent_.options[parent_.selectedIndex].value;
            return ParentVal_; // return parent_ value
        }

        function child_() {
            //something I cant figure out here ...
          }
    });
};
```

How can I display options in the child that only have the same values that the selected option in the parent?

Comment: You should have number of different child options for each parent. And depending on parent you need to use that particular object.

Comment: You cannot have a `<select>` within another `<select>`. You probably want to use something of this nature `<ul><li><ul><li></li></ul><li></li></li><li><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></li><li></li></ul>`. That is a strange nested list, to give you an idea of how to nest. Use `ul{ list-style:none; }` and the proper `ul>li:hover` with the correct selector in your CSS. Of course, then you need create the proper JavaScript dynamic dropdown Elements. We're not doing this for you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this script unless hidding but you can disable other options

```
    "use strict";
       window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById('category_select').addEventListener("change", 
         function() {
            parent_();
         });
       function parent_() {

        let parent_ = document.getElementById('category_select');
        let ParentVal_ = parent_.options[parent_.selectedIndex].value;
        child_(ParentVal_);
        //return ParentVal_; // return parent_ value
    }

    function child_(ParentVal_) {
        let child = document.getElementById('type_select');
        for (var i = 0; i < child.options.length; i++) {
            if (child.options[i].value == ParentVal_) {
                child.options[i].disabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                child.options[i].enabled = true;
            }
        }

      }
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following way:

Like I commented earlier you need to have different child values for each parent value and depending on selected parent you can render child options.

```js
var childs = {
  Electronics: [
    {
      label: 'Phone',
      value: 1
    },
    {
      label: 'Tablet',
      value: 2
    }
  ],
  Appliances: [
    {
      label: 'Refrigerator',
      value: 1
    },
    {
      label: 'Couch',
      value: 2
    },
    {
      label: 'Vaccum',
      value: 3
    }
  ]
}

function handleChange () {
  var x = document.getElementById("category_select").value;
  
  var childOptions = childs[x]
  var childSelect = document.getElementById('type_select')
  childSelect.innerHTML =''
  
  childOptions.forEach(function (option) {
    var optionEle = document.createElement('option')
    optionEle.value = option.value
    optionEle.label = option.label
    
    childSelect.appendChild(optionEle)
  })
  
}
handleChange()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  Parent:
  <select id="category_select" onChange='handleChange()'>
    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option value="Appliances">Appliances</option>
  </select>
  <br />

  Child: 
  <select id="type_select"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced my previous implementation with this, much more professional, although slightly frightening to get working at first :)

Answer (score 0):

i do not think it is a good idea to have value="1" in the option when you have to set the actual value for the option. I think we can use display none to hide the value like this

```
<head>
<style>
.hide {
  display: none
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<select id="category_select">
  <option value="1">Electronics</option>
  <option value="2">Appliances</option>
</select>

<select id="type_select">
  <option value="phones" category="1">Phones</option>
  <option value="tablets" category="1">Tablets</option>
  <option value="couch" category="2" class="hide">Couch</option>
  <option value="refrigerator" category="2" class="hide">Refrigerator</option>
  <option value="vacuum" category="2" class="hide">Vacuum</option>
</select>
</body>

<script>
document.getElementById('category_select').addEventListener("change", function() {
  var val = this.value;
  var options = document.getElementById('type_select').options;
  var new_val = null;
  for (var i = 0 ; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].attributes["category"].value === val) {
      if (!new_val) {
        new_val = options[i].value;
      }
      options[i].classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      options[i].classList.add("hide");
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('type_select').value = new_val;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my version on this.

```
const categorySelectEl = document.querySelector("#category_select");
const typeSelectEl = document.querySelector("#type_select");

categorySelectEl.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  renderSelectTypes(typeSelectEl, e.target.value);
});

function renderSelectTypes(el, selectedCategory) {
  const types = [['Phones', 'Tablets'], ['Couch', 'Refrigerator', 'Vacuum']];
  const options = types[Number(selectedCategory) - 1].map(item => `<option value="${selectedCategory}"">${item}</option>`)
  el.innerHTML = options.join("\n");
}

const currentlySelected = categorySelectEl.options[categorySelectEl.selectedIndex].value;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/lpqn3x0zw7